# How to obtain the username of the user that is logged in?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to save the username of the user who is logged in when he submits a post. How do I do it on Django's stock authentication system?

Comment: This is a legitimate question, but all due respect and given the quality of the Django docs about authentication, its laziness is unbearable.

Answer (score 3):

`request.user` represents the user currently logged in, see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user).

Comment: -1 - for what? This is an precise answer on the OP's question.

Comment: Looks like you really believe this one-liner is a quality answer. You may be technically correct, the best kind of correct...

Comment: @PauloScardine I see your point. But the quality of an answer is not measured in the length of it. The question is quite specific as you can see. I would be glad to improve the answer if I would see the user having additional questions. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: As I see it, the problem is not the length per se, but the fact that it could as well be a comment. I don't know if you deserve the downvote, but I think you don't deserve my upvote. You are a 46k user and has been around for some time, you can do better. :-)

Comment: @PauloScardine that's ok, I fully understand your point. Thanks again.